# juju-quickstart: error: bad API response: cannot upload charm to provider storage: 500 INKApi Error

Tags: juju, lxc

I have been able to use Juju from my home machine, however, when I attempt to use it from my work machine (which sits behind a proxy) I get:

(Output from juju quickstart --debug)

`retrieving the Juju API address
10:06:20 DEBUG utils@call:94 running the following: /usr/bin/juju api-endpoints -e local --format json
10:06:21 DEBUG utils@call:104 retcode: 0 | output: '["10.0.3.1:17070"]\n' | error: ''
connecting to wss://10.0.3.1:17070
10:06:21 DEBUG juju@send:130 API message: --> {"Request": "Login", "Params": {"Password": "password", "AuthTag": "user-admin"}, "Type": "Admin", "RequestId": 0}
10:06:21 DEBUG juju@recv:139 API message: <-- {"RequestId":0,"Response":{}}
requesting juju-gui deployment
charm URL: cs:precise/juju-gui-92
10:06:21 DEBUG juju@send:130 API message: --> {"Request": "ServiceDeploy", "Params": {"CharmURL": "cs:precise/juju-gui-92", "NumUnits": 0, "ToMachineSpec": null, "ServiceName": "juju-gui", "Config": {}, "Constraints": {}}, "Type": "Client", "RequestId": 1}
10:06:41 DEBUG juju@recv:139 API message: <-- {"RequestId":1,"Error":"cannot upload charm to provider storage: 500 500 INKApi Error","Response":{}}
juju-quickstart: error: bad API response: cannot upload charm to provider storage: 500 500 INKApi Error
ERROR exit status 1`

My .bashrc is set as:

`export http_proxy="http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080"
export https_proxy="http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080"
export ftp_proxy="http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080"
export HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080"
export HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080"
export FTP_PROXY="http://proxy.mycompany.com:8080"
export no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1"
export NO_PROXY="localhost,127.0.0.1"`

I have the proxy also set in /etc/default/lxc (for both, MIRROR and SECURITY_MIRROR) and verified LXC works.

When I run juju quickstart I create a new LXC local environment and I use defaults. This is installed on a bare Ubuntu 64-bit 14.04 install with the latest updates and juju-local and juju-quickstart packages. This also occurs if I try to deploy a local charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue.

After the environment is bootstrapped, changes to the environments.yaml file don't seem to take effect. The settings are pushed into the *.jenv file for that environment. Because I was using quickstart, the settings were pushed in prior to any changes made. The solution is to "juju destroy-environment --force", modify the environments.yaml file based on your needs, then perform a "juju bootstrap".

I stumbled on this when I unplugged my computer from the network, and removed ALL proxy settings everywhere and attempted to deploy a local charm. It still tried to use the proxy for 10.0.3.1. A "grep -r 'myproxy.com'" pointed to the *.jenv file.